# Cannot find PRAW config file when wrapping application with py2app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2app, praw

I'm trying to wrap my Python script into an application using py2app, but when I try to run the app I'm getting this PRAW related error:

Exception: Could not find config file in any of: ['/Users/username/CS/Applicationame/dist/applicationname.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/praw/praw.ini', '/Users/username/.config/praw.ini', 'praw.ini']

The strange thing is I navigated to the first path, unzipped site-packages.zip and found praw.ini inside /praw, so I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error. I've also tried using pyinstaller but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this error today - not in the context of py2app, but after a pip upgrade of praw. In case you still have this problem (unlikely :)) and/or in the interest of posterity, here's how I was able to fix it: I noticed that the error was in reading the praw.ini file, which very much exists on my system. The real problem was the owner of the file was root, and the owner only had read privileges. Changing that to have my account read/execute privileges to everything inside praw fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks! I actually left the project alone but came back to try this fixed and it worked!